# How can I use strtok() and getline() to read the lines of a file into a linked list?

Tags: c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>

struct node {
     char *name;
     struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node LINK;
struct node *head;
head = NULL;

int main(int argv, char **argc){

    // struct node *head, *current;
    //open the file
    int size;

    //for the strtok()
    const char space[1] = " ";
    //char *name;
    char *code;
    
    
    //for the getline()
    char *line;
    line = (char *)malloc(size);
    
    //number of characters in each line of file
    int oneline;
    
    
    FILE *fO;
    fO = fopen("hw5.data", "r");

    //check if file is not opening
    if(fO == NULL){
        printf("********************************************\n"); 
        printf("You must include a filename to load.\n");
        printf("********************************************\n");
    }

    
    //read the file data into the linked list
    int x = 0;
    while(getline(&line, &size, fO) != -1){
        char *name = strtok(line, " ");
        strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("Here is the name %s \n", name); 

        name = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("here's the code for name %s\n", name);

        x++;
        free(name);
    }

    free(line);
    //free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to use `strtok()` and `getline()` to read a file with a format of a name, 1 space and a single character per line like "Edward a" or "Bella d".  This program returns:

```
Heres the name Edward
here's the code for name (null)
```

instead of "(null)" I was hoping it would return 'a'.

I have read the man page for `strtok()` and `getline()`; I am still confused about it.  Does anyone know what the problem is? Sorry, I'm just required to use `strtok()` and `getline()`.

---

Here is the function I was talking about actually, I was trying to sort the linked list of strings with the strcmp(), to accordingly place the new string into the linked list. If the LinkedList was empty then Edward could be added. Otherwise, I tried to compare the input char name[] to the existing strings to put it in its place in ascending order.

```
//function to search list
int LIST_SEARCH(char name[], LINK *head) {
    LINK *current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
       if (!strcmp(current->name, name)){
           current = current->next;
           printf(" here it is 1.\n");
           printf("\n");
           return 1;
       }
       
   }
   printf("Did not find it.\n");
   printf("\n");

   return 0;                        
}

LINK *LIST_INSERT(char name[], LINK *head) {
    LINK *current, *temp1;
    if (LIST_SEARCH(name, head) == 1){
        return head;
    }   
    
    temp1 = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
    strcpy(temp1->name, name);

    //test if the list is empty.
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("empty\n");
        head = temp1; 
        temp1->next = NULL;
        return head;  
    } 
    
    //add the string to front of the list
    current = head;
    if(strcmp(current->name, name) > 0){
        printf("add name to front: %s\n", name);
        temp1->next  = current;
        head = temp1;
        return head;  
    } 
    //put the string at the back or middle of list
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {

       if (current->next == NULL || strcmp(current->next->name, name) > 0){
           printf("add name elsewhere: %s\n", name);
           temp1->next    = current->next;
           current->next = temp1;
           return head;  
       }
        //iterate 
       current = current->next;
    }
}
```

The function seemed to have added the first name. However, for the rest of the names, it does not execute the print statements and the program does not finish. It does not give errors either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your code is using C headers.  Do not dual-tag a question with C and C++ unless you particularly like downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have the code:

```
char *name = strtok(line, " ");
strtok(NULL, " ");
```

You can't afford to discard the result of the second call to `strtok()` like that — it contains the pointer to the code.  Remove that line!

There are other problems too.  You don't initialize `size`; it should be of type `size_t` anyway.  You have unused extraneous code in the question too.  You check whether the file was opened (though the message is a bit odd); that's good.  However, you continue to use the unopened file; that's bad.  You should report the error on standard error, not standard output.  It would be good to include the file name in the message.  It would be a good idea to zap the newline after reading the line.  You should not call `free(name)`.  The space allocated by `getline()` is pointed at by `line`, and you should (and do) call `free(line)` when the input loop completes.  The value returned by `strtok()` should not be freed; it does not allocate space, and the pointer returned is not guaranteed to the pointer returned by `malloc()`.

Here's working code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    char *line = 0;
    const char *filename = "hw5.data";
    FILE *fO = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fO == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (getline(&line, &size, fO) != -1)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = '\0';
        char *name = strtok(line, " ");
        char *code = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("Here is the name '%s'\n", name);
        printf("here's the code for name '%s'\n", code);
    }

    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

For the described input, it yields:

```
Here is the name 'Edward'
here's the code for name 'a'
Here is the name 'Bella'
here's the code for name 'd'
```

Note that when you get around to adding the data to your linked list, you'll need to duplicate the strings found — use `strdup()`.

---

Here is some code which creates, prints and releases a linked list using `strdup()` to copy the name.  Since the structure in the question has no place for storing the code, the code is printed while reading the data but otherwise ignored.  Note that I renamed the structure tag to `Node`, and used the tag as the typedef name too.  Also, note that there are no global (file scope) variables; you should avoid them as often as possible, which is most of the time.

```c
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    char *name;
    Node *next;
};

static Node *new_node(Node *head, const char *name)
{
    Node *np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
    if (np == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", sizeof(*np));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    np->name = strdup(name);
    if (np->name == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", strlen(name) + 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    np->next = head;
    return np;
}

static void print_list(const Node *head)
{
    const Node *curr = head;
    size_t count = 0;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%zu: [%s]\n", ++count, curr->name);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

static void free_list(Node *head)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        Node *next = curr->next;
        free(curr->name);
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "hw5.data";
    FILE *fO = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fO == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Node *head = NULL;

    size_t size = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    while (getline(&line, &size, fO) != -1)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = '\0';
        char *name = strtok(line, " ");
        char *code = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("Here is the name '%s'\n", name);
        printf("Here is the code '%s'\n", code);
        head = new_node(head, name);
    }
    free(line);

    print_list(head);
    free_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

I used this as the data file `hw5.data`:

```
Edward a
Bella d
Jacob a
Renesmee b
Jasper c
Rosalie b
Alice a
Carlisle a
```

The output from the program is then:

```
Here is the name 'Edward'
Here is the code 'a'
Here is the name 'Bella'
Here is the code 'd'
Here is the name 'Jacob'
Here is the code 'a'
Here is the name 'Renesmee'
Here is the code 'b'
Here is the name 'Jasper'
Here is the code 'c'
Here is the name 'Rosalie'
Here is the code 'b'
Here is the name 'Alice'
Here is the code 'a'
Here is the name 'Carlisle'
Here is the code 'a'
1: [Carlisle]
2: [Alice]
3: [Rosalie]
4: [Jasper]
5: [Renesmee]
6: [Jacob]
7: [Bella]
8: [Edward]
```

I use quotes and square brackets around the names to demonstrate that there are no extraneous characters.

Comment: thank you so much @Jonathan.  since strtok() returns a string I was trying to use a strcmp() to compare the 'code' to "a" to evaluate if I need 'a'dd it to a linked list.  I did strtok(code, "a") and tried other ways to compare it but they did not work, do you know what the issue is?  I read the manual page too.  It must be a small problem, I just am not sure. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: to add more details about the problem, strcmp() is returning a '1' for every element of the file except for the last one which it correctly identifies.  it is really confusing.

Comment: Remember that `strtok()` returns a pointer to part of the string that it analyzes; it does not make/allocate a copy of the string.  That's why I mentioned "you'll need to duplicate the strings found — use `strdup()`".  If you use `getline()` the normal way, each successive input line overwrites the previous one.  This may well be why the last one is correct and the rest are not.  (There are ways to avoid that, but the memory management is much harder.)

Comment: I tried using strdup() but only problem seemed to be the newline '\0' at the end of the string. I used strcspn() to remove the newline; the program ran well. Now, I am trying to add the names into an empty linked list with a function, which seems to add the first name and then stops.  Would I still need to use strdup()?  the function header is like:`LINK *insert(char name[], LINK *head){}`

Comment: sorry @jonathan, the strdup() did not work well with iterating through a linked list.  Do you think the function would have to pass in the head pointer by reference since it is returning a struct node type? after detecting an 'a', I thought to insert the first string name into the linked list.  `if(head == NULL){ head = temp; temp->next = NULL; return head;`  It looked simple, am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @txdara — see the updated answer.  Without seeing your code, it is not possible to guess what you were doing wrong.

Comment: @jonathan-I included the code for the function I mentioned.   Sorry, I should have made an edit first.  The function seemed straightforward enough.  I thought it would be able to take the string without the '\0' as one parameter, and the head as the other.

Comment: I'll look at your code later when I get home from work on the ski slopes.

Comment: Byte arrays without a terminal null byte are not strings.  (Thank you, O Spell Mangler on my iPhone, for the previous inscrutable mess.)  By definition, a string is a sequence of characters terminated by a null byte.

Comment: I observe that `LIST_SEARCH()` is not defined — please ensure that your code is complete.  Read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  It isn't too hard to guess what the function does (assuming it _is_ a function; normally, though, all upper-case is used to indicate a macro or compilation constant).

Comment: sorry, I was still modifying the LIST_SEARCH(), the issue might be the list search. I just included it.

Comment: Thanks.  One obvious major problem is in the second of the two lines: `temp1 = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK)); strcpy(temp1->name, name);` — what does `temp1->name` point at?  The answer is "you have no idea" because you've not allocated any space for it to point to, nor have you initialized it.  However, replacing the second line with `temp1->name = strdup(name);` is not sufficient to solve the problem.  There are too many special cases in the insert code for comfort.  I'm working on how to fix that.

Comment: The loop in `LIST_SEARCH()` is bogus: `while (current != NULL) { if (!strcmp(current->name, name)) { current = current->next; printf(" here it is 1.\n"); printf("\n"); return 1; } }` — it doesn't change `current` when the string comparison fails, so it is an infinite loop.  You need something more like: `while (current != NULL) { if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0) { printf("here it is 1.\n\n"); return 1; } current = current->next; }`, where the `current = current->next;` is outside the `if` block.  With the `strdup()` change and that change, the code works reasonably well.